# uploading files greather than 4096KB fails!

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, web-config

I'm setting up an asp.net (asp.net framework 4.0) webproject with visual Studio 2010. In one of my webpage I use a silverlight mulit file uploader from the link below:

[Silverlight Mulit File uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/)

I set the max upload size from the plugin to 100 MB as you can see on the code below.

```
 <object id="MultiFileUploader" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
    width="465" height="220">
    <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/mpost.SilverlightMultiFileUpload.xap" />
    <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="initParams" value="MaxFileSizeKB=102400,MaxUploads=2,FileFilter=Bilder(*.jpg *.png *.gif*)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif|Dokumente(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Videos(*.mpeg *.avi *.wma)|*.mpeg;*.avi;*.wma|Audio(*.mp3)|*.mp3,ChunkSize=4194304,CustomParams=yourparameters,DefaultColor=White" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration: none">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
            style="border-style: none" />
    </a>
</object>
<iframe style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'></iframe>
```

I also made some entries in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360" />
    <sessionState
      mode="InProc"
      timeout="30"
      cookieless="false"
      cookieName="MMAdminPfynSession"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Everytime I upload a file bigger than 4096 KB the upload-process fails. I start my webapplication out from Visual studio 2010 while pressing ctrl-F5. Any ideas?

Greez Marc

Comment: What error/exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to increase the `maxRequestLength` and `execution time`.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360" />
```

Comment: those are in his web.config...line 6

Comment: maxRequestLength seems to OK, but executionTimeout is the problem I think. If he increase I think problem will be solved.

Comment: No it sadly has the same effect! Any other ideas where i can set some properties to fixt this? I also tried this code to read the maxRequestLength during runtime, and it always returned me 4096:                                                                  System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection section = new System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection();
        string output = section.MaxRequestLength.ToString();

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: While uploading, the silverlight plugin first creates a temp-file instead of the origial. When the error occours, the silverlight plugin just giving me an errordialog --> upload failed. Then.. when I take a look on the produced temp-file in the filesystem..the size is always 4096 KB. Are there some restrictions in the visual studion 2010? Does it only works after setting up an IIS?

Comment: Default limit (4mb) in a localized way by dropping a web.config in the directory where your upload page lives. That way you don't have to make your whole site allow huge uploads (doing so would open you up to a certain kinds of attacks).

Comment: Also check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828288/why-is-webclient-uploadfileasync-not-working-with-large-file-uploads/5828337#5828337

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: You mean putting a new web.config with the correct entries in that project directory, where the upload page lives, and delete the httpRuntime-entries in the "main" web.config? I know that will be a better way because of security things.., but I hope it will also allow me bigger uploads! I'll gona try it..

Comment: yah, put it that web.config and let me know your findings.